# kdb q - splaying tables from slave processes

Tags: kdb

I have an expensive function

```
mainfunc:{[batch;savepath] 
     ...compute large table depending on batch and save it to savepath...
}
```

which is copied to slave *processes* and each process handles a different `batch` input to the function.
Say I need to execute the function on `input:til 1000` then process 1 executes `mainfunc[input[til 50];savepath]` and process 2 executes `mainfunc[input[50+til 50]]`. Since they are processes and not threads saving to file is possible.

The reason why I am trying to avoid threads is that the output from `mainfunc` is a large table and there would be a lot of serialization overhead if the table was sent to the main process and saved from there.

Now I am running into the limitation that I want to splay the large table in each process. However splaying (in the case of table with symbols) requires to modify the `sym` file kept for enumeration and I get an exception as soon as 2 processes are trying to access that `sym` file. I use something like

```
splaydirname set .Q.en[hsym `$savepath] largetable; / .Q.en locks the sym file enumeration is done
```

How can I work around that?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? I was under the impression that the enumeration shouldn't be a problem *because* of the lock on the sym file. I think your bigger problem will be the fact that you're writing to a splayed table concurrently.........writing to a splayed table is not an atomic operation (it writes column by column) and so if two processes are writing to the same table at the same time you could end up with a corrupt/jagged table where not all columns have the same length

Comment: each process saves their own table, e.g. process 1 creates `/dir/t1/`, process 2 creates `/dir/t2/` but in `/dir/` I would have a common `sym` file (created by `.Q.en`) which might be modified concurrently and gives the exception " noupdate: \`. `sym"

Comment: How are you setting up the slave processing......using `-s` with a negative number (aka distributed each)? If so then this functionality might also be subject to the `noupdate` restriction. You might have to manually spin up and manage slave processes yourself using standard IPC rather than using the built-in tools. I believe the concurrent enumerations should work then